# How to read a specified number of bytes from a specified offset from a file

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

I would like to read a specified number of bytes from the specified offset value from a file. I pass the offset, a number of bytes, filename as arguments to the file. The code below does not work.Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define buf_size 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int bytes;
    int offset;
    int fd;
    int i = 0;
    int length = 0;
    ssize_t read_bytes;
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size];

    if (argc != 4)
        error(1, 0, "Too many or less than the number of arguments");
    file = argv[1];
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error while opening the file\n");
    while (1) {
        read_bytes = read(fd, buf, bytes);
        if (read_bytes == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error while reading the file\n");
        length += read_bytes;
        printf("The length is : %d\n", length);
        if (length >= offset) {
            for (i = length ; i < bytes; i++)
                putchar(buf[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (close(fd) == -1)
        error(1, 0, "Error while closing the file\n");

}
```

Comment: Look up `lseek`.

Comment: Also, think about what your program does if `offset` is not a multiple of `bytes`, or if `bytes` is larger than `buf_size`.

Comment: A problem's description "The code below does not work"  is not the one with which we can help you. What is your input? What is output of your code? What output do you expect from it? Please, read [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok sure.Sorry for the mistake. Would not repeat the mistake again.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to replace some POSIX functions with the ones found in the C standard library due to constraints pointed out by the person who asked the question. This is fairly portable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#define buf_size 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int bytes;
    int offset;
    FILE *fd;
    int i = 0;
    ssize_t read_bytes;
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size];

    if (argc != 4)
        printf("Too many or less than the number of arguments\n");
    file = argv[1];
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    fd = fopen(file, "r");
    if (fd == NULL)
        perror("ERROR");
    fseek(fd, offset, SEEK_SET);
    read_bytes = fread(buf, 1, bytes, fd);
    if (read_bytes == 0) {
        if (feof(fd))
            printf("ERROR: End of file.\n");
        else if (ferror(fd))
            printf("ERROR: Unable to read the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
        putchar(buf[i]);
    if (fclose(fd) == EOF)
        perror("ERROR:");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks,  But I have a constraint of not using lseek system call. Thank  you.

Comment: Alright, use read() itself instead, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What operating system? I have written this on Ubuntu.

Comment: Debian 9 using it in VirtualBox. @stare

Comment: Are you allowed to use the functions in the C standard library?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the open, close, read, write system calls only for the above-mentioned question.I think it takes care of partial reads, offset > buf_size and bytes > buf_size.Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#define buf_size 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int bytes;
    int offset;
    int fd; 
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size];
    int rlen = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int i = 0;

    if (argc != 4)
        error(1, 0, "Too many or less than the number of arguments");
    file = argv[1];
    offset = atoi(argv[2]);
    bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    printf("The values of the file descriptor is : %d\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error while opening the file\n");

    while (1) {
        rlen = read(fd, buf, offset);
        if (rlen == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error in reading the file\n");
        len = len + rlen;
        if(len == offset) {
            len = 0;
            while (1) {
                rlen = read(fd, buf, bytes);
                if (rlen == -1)
                    error(1, errno, "Error in reading the file\n");
                if (rlen == 0)
                    return 0;
                len = len + rlen;
                for (i = 0; i < rlen; i++) 
                    putchar(buf[i]);
                if (len == bytes) {
                    printf("\nSuccess\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                bytes = bytes - rlen;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nate Eldredge could you please review this. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @strance Thanks for your help. Would you mind checking this?